# Calling a returned function

Tags: javascript, function

So I am trying to write a general memoizing function in Javascript, using [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/implementing-memoization-in-javascript/) as my reference material. I've implemented it as instructed:

```js
function memoize(func) {
  var memo = {};
  var slice = Array.prototype.slice;

  return function() {
    var args = slice.call(arguments);

    if (args in memo)
      return memo[args]
    else
      return (memo[args] = func.apply(this, args));
  }
}

function fibonacci(n) {
  if (n === 0 || n === 1)
    return n;
  else
    return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
}

function memoFib = memoize(fibonacci);

console.log("Fibonacci of 6 is " + memoFib(6));
```

but for the life of me I cannot remember the proper syntax to calling the memoized function. How do I do this? How do I generalize this so that it's the memoized fibonacci function which is always called instead of the original function fibonacci?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there; you just need to fix your syntax when creating the memoized function. Instead of `function memoFib =`, do `var memoFib =` (or if ES2015 is an option, `const` would be better than `var`). And presumably you'll want to have the recursion calling into the memoized version as well, so i updated those as well. In the following code it may look weird that i'm referencing memoFib on a line that comes earlier than the line with `var memoFib` but javascript allows that due to [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting).

```js
function memoize(func) {
  var memo = {};
  var slice = Array.prototype.slice;

  return function() {
    var args = slice.call(arguments);

    if (args in memo)
      return memo[args]
    else
      return (memo[args] = func.apply(this, args));
  }
}

function fibonacci(n) {
  if (n === 0 || n === 1)
    return n;
  else
    return memoFib(n - 1) + memoFib(n - 2);
}

var memoFib = memoize(fibonacci);

console.log("Fibonacci of 6 is " + memoFib(6));
```

And if you want to make absolutely sure no one can ever invoke the nonmemoized version, then you can hide it inside of an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression):

```
const fibonacci = (function () {
  function unmemoizedVersion(n) {
    if (n === 0 || n === 1)
      return n;
    else
      return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
  }
  return memoize(unmemoizedVersion);
})();
```